# DoNotTrack Safari extension by Abine

Tags: safari-extensions

I'm desperate to uninstall the DoNotTrackMe extension from Abine.com. The cure is worse than the disease in this case. I've used the "Uninstall" button in the Extensions pane in Safari, and it supposedly removes it, but even then sites such as Yahoo news and Asana won't work properly until I reinstall their extension and click on the DoNotTrackMe button.

I've looked in the Library folder to see if I can find any sneaky additions, but I don't see anything in Preferences or Application Support or the Safari folder that would indicate that Abine is doing anything more than installing the extension. Help?

Answer (score 1):

They have changed your Proxy settings.

Proxy is a way to connect to Internet true a specific gate (server).

Doing that the Track Me is hidden from others since they now do not know who you are.

To fix that Open the Proxy settings in Safari and unchecked anything in the pop up window.

Then Reset the Safari.

Comment: Thanks buscar. I thought you might have the solution there, but my proxy settings are all set to the normal defaults, even with the extension installed.

Comment: @DRaymond I am sure it is that, just need to find it where it is, your Safari is been redirected true a proxy server. To check tell me the address that is showing. Is it just http://news.yahoo.com/ or something else? I am sure other browsers work, if you have them.

Comment: Buscar, thanks for sticking with me here. In the case of Asana.com, the URL is app.asana.com, which it always has been. I wasn't clear on the Yahoo news part -- it actually only happens when I'm being redirected from news stories in a daily e-mail, which direct to https://svtracking1.communications.yahoo.com. So obviously they are trying to track the origin of the click via the URL, and it makes sense that DoNotTrackMe would block it, since it's designed to prevent tracking your internet usage. Another detail is that these sites _will_ load once I click the DNT button...

Comment: I am baffled that it is still active even after you disabled all extensions in Safari. I will do some more research and get back to you :)